# vba-MSAccess do same thing on several textbox event

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to do the same thing in the key up textbox.
Ex. I have several textbox to key in. And I want to auto calculate the average in the last of the textbox. So I need to use the event key on. But I have lots of textbox to do it, I should click many times to do it. Is there any suggestions? Like class method? write a loop to do it? My code:

```
Private Sub gsm1_ave_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    Dim gsm1, gsm2, gsm3, gsm4, gsm5 As Variant
    gsm1 = Me.gsm1_1
    gsm2 = Me.gsm1_2
    gsm3 = Me.gsm1_3
    gsm4 = Me.gsm1_4
    gsm5 = Me.gsm1_5
    Me.gsm1_ave = (gsm1 + gsm2 + gsm3 + gsm4 + gsm5) / 5
End Sub

Private Sub gsm2_ave_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    Dim gsm1, gsm2, gsm3, gsm4, gsm5 As Variant
    gsm1 = Me.gsm2_1
    gsm2 = Me.gsm2_2
    gsm3 = Me.gsm2_3
    gsm4 = Me.gsm2_4
    gsm5 = Me.gsm2_5
    Me.gsm2_ave = (gsm1 + gsm2 + gsm3 + gsm4 + gsm5) / 5
End Sub

Private Sub gsm3_ave_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    Dim gsm1, gsm2, gsm3, gsm4, gsm5 As Variant
    gsm1 = Me.gsm3_1
    gsm2 = Me.gsm3_2
    gsm3 = Me.gsm3_3
    gsm4 = Me.gsm3_4
    gsm5 = Me.gsm3_5
    Me.gsm3_ave = (gsm1 + gsm2 + gsm3 + gsm4 + gsm5) / 5
End Sub
```

Comment: http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/08/05/vba-control-arrays/

Comment: wow, that's helpful to me. Thank you!

Comment: Can those gsm1_? fields contain Null?

Comment: @HansUp the field type:single. can contain Null.The sub I write cannot work if that contain Null. Can I according to the column you keyin and do the average?

Comment: Based on your reply to Oliver, I think you want to revise the procedure to sum the non-Null values.  That means you will also need to count the number of non-values so you can compute the average.

Comment: Updated link : http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. You may want to try doing this in the _Change event instead of KeyUp, because what you really want to do i recalculate the average when the value in the textbox changes, not when a key is pressed.
2. If you rewrite your code to

   `Me.gsm1_ave = (Me.gsm1_1 + Me.gsm1_2 + Me.gsm1_3 + Me.gsm1_4 + Me.gsm1_5) / 5`

   It looks like just one line to me. Not too much overhead. But yes, if you want to recalculate your average when any of these textboxes changes, you need to handle the _Change event in all 5 boxes, doing the same line in each.

Answer (score 0):

The *easy* thing to do here is to extract that functionality into a subroutine.

```
Private Sub HandleKeyPressEvent(cntrl)
    Dim gsm1, gsm2, gsm3, gsm4, gsm5 As Variant
    gsm1 = Me.gsm3_1
    gsm2 = Me.gsm3_2
    gsm3 = Me.gsm3_3
    gsm4 = Me.gsm3_4
    gsm5 = Me.gsm3_5
    cntrl = (gsm1 + gsm2 + gsm3 + gsm4 + gsm5) / 5
End Sub
```

And then call it from the events.

```
Private Sub gsm1_ave_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    HandleKeyPressEvent Me.gsm1_ave
End Sub

Private Sub gsm2_ave_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    HandleKeyPressEvent Me.gsm2_ave
End Sub

Private Sub gsm3_ave_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    HandleKeyPressEvent Me.gsm2_ave
End Sub
```

Comment: My first thought, too, but his code suggests that the controls that go into the average are _different_ in each of the three cases.

Comment: I fixed it @Oliver. Just need to pass the control into the sub. Preferably strongly typed (unlike my code here). I wasn't sure what type of controls were being passed.

Comment: Sorry, not quite... Me.gsm3_1 is only going _into_ the calculation in the last case. In the first case it's Me.gsm1_1

Comment: Then post an answer @Oliver. I gave the concept to OP. It's not my job to write the code for him. Maybe some reasonable names would make the code readable enough for a proper answer, but as it is I have already donated more than enough of my time.